# I can't seem to comprehend electrical circuits

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, electrical-engineering

I don't seem to fully get the mechanism going on. A potential difference is applied, then an electric field pushes electrons from low potential to high potential. Now, a few questions:

1. If electric potential is different between two different sides of a resistor (because there is a potential drop), does that mean bringing a charge from infinity to a point just after a resistor will require less work to be done than bringing it to "before" the resistor? It seems too vague for me, is electric potential being treated different than in electrostatics? The direction of "drop" is determined by the current's direction, doesn't it? I would like to understand how it connects with the electrostatic potential.
2. When the current gets into a node, does it ALWAYS diverge into every possible way? Sometimes it means "going back" to where there was already current from another node. How does it work? It seems magical to me, and it just tells me I have a lack of understanding. When does it diverge to every branch and when doesn't it, and why? I suppose the current "wishes" to get to the lower potential, but it seems to be determined by the resistance midway, how is that possible? Does the current "know" where to go depending on an upcoming resistor?

A jumble of questions, which might be obvious for other people but stop me from getting this entire section in the grand topic of Electricity And Magnetism.

Comment: In point 1, instead of using infinity as the point of $0$ potential, why not just use the negative terminal of the battery?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) If electric potential is different between two different sides of a
>   resistor (because there is a potential drop), does that mean bringing
>   a charge from infinity to a point just after a resistor will require
>   less work to be done than bringing it to "before" the resistor?

The potential difference V between two points is the work required per unit charge to move the charge between the two points. The potential difference between the ends of a resistor carrying current means that one end of the resistor is more "negative" relative to the other side of the resistor. That means more work would be required to move negative charge from infinity to the more negative terminal of the resistor than to bring the same charge to the more positive terminal of the resistor. The same would apply to moving the negative charge from infinity to the negative terminal of a battery than to the positive terminal.

> 2) When the current gets into a node, does it ALWAYS diverge into
>   every possible way? Sometimes it means "going back" to where there was
>   already current from another node. How does it work?

Per Kirchhoff's current law (KCL), the algebraic sum of the currents into a node is zero. That's the only criteria that needs to be satisfied. The basis of this law is the conservation of charge. If an amount of current flows to a node from another node and the same amount of current returns to originating node that in itself would not violate KCL. However, how that actually happens would depend on the details of the circuit.

> When does it diverge to every branch and when doesn't it, and why?

To answer a question like that, you would need to know all the details of the circuit. The question as it stands is too broad to answer.

Hope this helps.